# Two-column figures and tables disappear when changebar is used

Tags: changebar

I want to insert a bar in the margin in IEEEtran, but when I use changebar package, two-column figures and tables disappear. It is my code:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[color]{changebar}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{xspace}
\cbcolor{black}
\sethlcolor{yellow}
\newcommand{\edit}[1]{\cbstart\hl{#1}\cbend\xspace}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure*}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=15cm]{example-image}\\
\end{figure*}

\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

I would really appreciate if you can provide any help.

Comment: Thanks I can confirm that same happens here, the float is dropped, Interesting....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`changebar` is an old package and it redefines several latex internals in particular the float handling.

It turns out not to be fully compatible with the double float handling in 2015/01/01 latex release (which fixed several bugs in that area)

this works, until changebar is updated:

```
\RequirePackage[2014/01/01]{latexrelease}
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[color]{changebar}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{xspace}
\cbcolor{black}
\sethlcolor{yellow}
\newcommand{\edit}[1]{\cbstart\hl{#1}\cbend\xspace}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure*}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=15cm]{example-image}
\end{figure*}

\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get around the same problem by copying `changebar.sty` from my distribution (TeX Live 2015, but the file has not been updated in ~10 years), and removing the float-related macros -

```
\let\end@float\cb@end@float               % remove from here
\let\flt@float@end\float@end
  ·
  ·
  ·
  \flt@float@dblend
  }                                       % up until here
```

Rename the new file to e.g. `mychangebar.sty` and `\usepackage{mychangebar}` it instead of the stock `changebar`.

I did this after trying the accepted solution and noticing that it changed my layout completely due to the different behavior of floats in 2014. Of course, this means your changebars will not work in or across floats; a more thorough rewriting of these macros is needed for a true fix.

Comment: I don't think this works any longer. I have tried it (and after it did not work I have removed *all* references to floats from the sty) to no avail with texlive 2018.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `changebar.sty` replaces some latex kernel macros. The relevant macro in this case is `\end@float`.

If you wish, you may try the following solution (works for me with `twocol`)

1. Add this to the preamble of your document:

   ```
   \makeatletter
   \newcommand{\cboff}{\let\end@float\ltx@end@float}
   \newcommand{\cbon}{\let\end@float\cb@end@float}
   \makeatother
   ```
2. Add the commands `\cboff`, `\cbon` before and after `\begin{figure*}` and `\end{figure*}`, respectively. For example

   ```
   \cboff
   \begin{figure*}
   ...
   \end{figure*}
   \cbon
   ```

It is a silly workaround, but it seems to work.

Comment: Seems to have no effect (at least with the acmart class).

Comment: I concur. I have a MWE with `\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}` where this workaround does not work.